# filtering rows with same condition on more than one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to select rows based using the same condition across different columns.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(col.x = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 col.y = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 val = rnorm(20))
```

I need to have only the values in `ValsToRetain` across two columns `col.x`, `col.y`.

```
ValsToRetain <- c('A','D', 'F','H','J')
```

I have tried these two approaches which give the same expected output.

```
df %>% filter(col.x %in% ValsToRetain) %>% filter(col.y %in% ValsToRetain)
df %>% filter(col.x %in% ValsToRetain & col.y %in% ValsToRetain)
#   col.x col.y        val
# 1     A     H -1.6866933
# 2     F     F  0.8377870
# 3     J     J  0.4264642
# 4     F     H  0.8781335
# 5     D     D -0.3059627
```

But, is there any other elegant way(s) to do this?

For example; like calculating `rowSums` across these columns to check if it has `na`s or not. As there are more than one value, I could not get a similar idea like `rowSums(df[,1:2] == 'A')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `filter_at` with `all_vars`

```
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("col")), all_vars(. %in% ValsToRetain))
#   col.x col.y        val
#1     A     H -1.6866933
#2     F     F  0.8377870
#3     J     J  0.4264642
#4     F     H  0.8781335
#5     D     D -0.3059627
```

Comment: Thanks, it is definitely an elegant way of doing it. Do you see other approaches if the col names would have been `xvar`, `yvar`
, `valvar`? Is it `filter_at(vars('xvar', 'yvar'), all_vars(. %in% ValsToRetain))` ?? Btw, which version of `dplyr` are you using? I am getting an error `could not find function "filter_at"`.

Comment: You can take the negated version of vars, i.e. `df %>% filter_at(vars(-val), all_vars(. %in% ValsToRetain))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method using `Reduce` and `lapply`. The `lapply` applies `%in%` across the relevant columns, returning a list of logical vectors. Then `Reduce` combines these vectors into a single vector using `&`.

```
df[Reduce("&", lapply(df[c("col.x", "col.y")], "%in%", ValsToRetain)),]
   col.x col.y        val
6      A     H -1.6866933
7      F     F  0.8377870
11     J     J  0.4264642
14     F     H  0.8781335
19     D     D -0.3059627
```

If you have many columns for the comparison, then you could use `grep` to select them like `grep("^col", names(df))` in place of `c("col.x", "col.y")`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use subset, it's pretty short but the same way than your method:

```
filt <- subset(df,col.x %in% ValsToRetain & col.y %in% ValsToRetain)
```

The output is:

```
 col.x col.y        val
     A     H -1.6866933
     F     F  0.8377870
     J     J  0.4264642
     F     H  0.8781335
     D     D -0.3059627
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as OP's second option *df %>% filter(col.x %in% ValsToRetain & col.y %in% ValsToRetain)* - You just used `subset` instead of `filter`

Comment: @Sotos That's exactly what i said "the same way than your method" so you don't have to put a downvote i guess

Comment: Well, I feel the downvote is justifiable here as OP seeks for *any other elegant way(s) to do this*... I mean you can update with something different to at least give some value to your answer and I will be glad to reverse my vote. Something along the lines of `df %>% mutate_at(vars(-val), funs((replace(., !. %in% ValsToRetain, NA)))) %>% na.omit()` for example should do

Comment: Though it is exactly same as the one I have mentioned, thanks for reminding the baseR function!